# rails: add a attribute to a option tag through collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a collection_select:

```
f.collection_select(:selected_id, @subcategories, :id, :cat_transl)
```

which turns into the following tags:

```
<option value="4">Deutsch</option>
<option value="5">Chinesisch</option>
<option value="6">Spanisch</option>
<option value="10">Mathematik</option>
```

What I want is to add a attribute to every option

```
<option value="4" parent="3">Deutsch</option>
<option value="5" parent="3">Chinesisch</option>
<option value="6" parent="3">Spanisch</option>
<option value="10" parent="9">Mathematik</option>
```

How is this possible?

Thanks 
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your really need this attribute despite the fact it's invalid HTML, use a "content_tag" helper method. You can build any tag with it manually.

```
<%= content_tag(:tag_name, 'text value',  { :value => 'form_value', :anyattr => 'my_val' }) %>
```

Comment: I solved it by changing the user interface. I guess this would have done it too. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the built-in Rails helpers, probably because it's not valid HTML. You can see which attributes the `option` element supports here:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp